# How overcome, if possible, Time Series limitation acting directly on bucket collection

Tags: mongodb, time-series

I'm exploring how to use the Time Series collection in a MongoDB replica set (on-premise community edition 6.0.6).
I have define a TS collection as below:

```
{
  name:"ts1",
  type:"timeseries",
  options:{
    timeseries:{
      timeField:"timestamp",
      metaField:"meta",
      granularity: "seconds",
      bucketMaxSpanSeconds: 3600
      }
    },
    info: {readonly: false}
},
```

Below same example data from "db.system.buckets.ts1":

```
 {
            _id: ObjectId("646b3ff0c5a28d25568373ae"),
            control: {
                  version: 1,
                  min: {
                        timestamp: ISODate("2023-05-22T10:12:00.000Z"),
                        cowe: 201.939,
                        pmnp10: 14,
                        hum: 62.3,
                        pmnp50: 0,
                        pmspug10: 3,
                        pm10: 60.37,
                        calpm10: '',
                        no2ae: 397.264,
                        calco: '',
                        batt: 100,
                        temp: 24,
                        pmnp05: 166,
                        co: 0.583,
                        pmspug100: 4,
                        pmaeug10: 3,
                        no2: 50.284,
                        vafe: 262.362,
                        pmnp100: 0,
                        pmaeug25: 4,
                        no2o3ae: 409.052,
                        calpm2_5: '',
                        pmaeug100: 4,
                        no2we: 109.925,
                        pm25: 198.91,
                        no2o3we: 422.077,
                        calno2: '',
                        pmnp03: 537,
                        calo3: '',
                        pmnp25: 4,
                        pmspug25: 4,
                        coae: 160.378,
                        pmdiag: 0,
                        o3: 40.285,
                        _id: ObjectId("646efee320e52ccbfd5ef937")
                  },
                  max: {
                        timestamp: ISODate("2023-05-22T10:13:00.000Z"),
                        cowe: 300.939,
                        pmnp10: 14,
                        hum: 62.3,
                        pmnp50: 0,
                        pmspug10: 3,
                        pm10: 60.37,
                        calpm10: 'test',
                        no2ae: 397.264,
                        calco: '',
                        batt: 100,
                        temp: 24,
                        pmnp05: 166,
                        co: 0.583,
                        pmspug100: 4,
                        pmaeug10: 3,
                        no2: 50.284,
                        vafe: 262.362,
                        pmnp100: 0,
                        pmaeug25: 4,
                        no2o3ae: 409.052,
                        calpm2_5: 'test',
                        pmaeug100: 4,
                        no2we: 109.925,
                        pm25: 198.91,
                        no2o3we: 422.077,
                        calno2: '',
                        pmnp03: 537,
                        calo3: 'test',
                        pmnp25: 4,
                        pmspug25: 4,
                        coae: 160.378,
                        pmdiag: 0,
                        o3: 40.285,
                        _id: ObjectId("646eff3220e52ccbfd5ef939")
                  }
            },
            meta: {
                  idafe: 'AirH358',
                  lbllocation: 'Poli-TO-1',
                  location: {
                        coordinates: [15.047446452336533, 37.36084832653023],
                        type: 'Point'
                  },
                  schemaver: 1,
                  verfmw: 'AH_1.3.1'
            },
            data: {
                  vafe: {
                        '0': 262.362,
                        '1': 262.362
                  },
                  no2we: {
                        '0': 109.925,
                        '1': 109.925
                  },
                  cowe: {
                        '0': 201.939,
                        '1': 300.939
                  },
                  no2: {
                        '0': 50.284,
                        '1': 50.284
                  },
                  coae: {
                        '0': 160.378,
                        '1': 160.378
                  },
                  calco: {
                        '0': '',
                        '1': ''
                  },
                  temp: {
                        '0': 24,
                        '1': 24
                  },
                  pmnp10: {
                        '0': 14,
                        '1': 14
                  },
                  timestamp: {
                        '0': ISODate("2023-05-22T10:12:00.000Z"),
                        '1': ISODate("2023-05-22T10:13:00.000Z")
                  },
                  no2o3ae: {
                        '0': 409.052,
                        '1': 409.052
                  },
                  calno2: {
                        '0': '',
                        '1': ''
                  },
                  pmaeug100: {
                        '0': 4,
                        '1': 4
                  },
                  o3: {
                        '0': 40.285,
                        '1': 40.285
                  },
                  pmnp03: {
                        '0': 537,
                        '1': 537
                  },
                  hum: {
                        '0': 62.3,
                        '1': 62.3
                  },
                  pm25: {
                        '0': 198.91,
                        '1': 198.91
                  },
                  _id: {
                        '0': ObjectId("646efee320e52ccbfd5ef937"),
                        '1': ObjectId("646eff3220e52ccbfd5ef939")
                  },
                  pmdiag: {
                        '0': 0,
                        '1': 0
                  },
                  pmnp100: {
                        '0': 0,
                        '1': 0
                  },
                  no2ae: {
                        '0': 397.264,
                        '1': 397.264
                  },
                  pmaeug25: {
                        '0': 4,
                        '1': 4
                  },
                  pmspug25: {
                        '0': 4,
                        '1': 4
                  },
                  pmspug100: {
                        '0': 4,
                        '1': 4
                  },
                  pmaeug10: {
                        '0': 3,
                        '1': 3
                  },
                  batt: {
                        '0': 100,
                        '1': 100
                  },
                  pmnp50: {
                        '0': 0,
                        '1': 0
                  },
                  pm10: {
                        '0': 60.37,
                        '1': 60.37
                  },
                  calpm2_5: {
                        '0': '',
                        '1': 'test'
                  },
                  pmnp05: {
                        '0': 166,
                        '1': 166
                  },
                  pmnp25: {
                        '0': 4,
                        '1': 4
                  },
                  calpm10: {
                        '0': '',
                        '1': 'test'
                  },
                  no2o3we: {
                        '0': 422.077,
                        '1': 422.077
                  },
                  co: {
                        '0': 0.583,
                        '1': 0.583
                  },
                  pmspug10: {
                        '0': 3,
                        '1': 3
                  },
                  calo3: {
                        '0': '',
                        '1': 'test'
                  }
            }
      }
```

I would like to be able some sensor readings by timestamp or index, i.e. delete readings having index 1 or readings whose timestamp is greater than a set timestamp, but I'm not able to figure out how to design such a type of query given this specific schema.
Any suggestion/example?
Thanks!